# ConcurrentBag how to change object property

Tags: c#, synchronization, thread-safety

I have QueueItem object with one property. I need to find it in ConcurrentBag list and change it value. How to do that?

```
QueueItemList = new ConcurrentBag<QueueItem>()
```

I can use linq to query object in ConcurrentBag like this

```
MyItem =  QueueItemList.Where(match);
MyItem.Status = changeThis;
```

but is this thread safe?

Comment: What do you mean by "thread-safe", exactly? What scenarios are you envisaging that could cause problems, and what does your item have in it around thread safety?

Comment: QueueItem object do not have any thread-safe locking and I need to create Queue list of QueueItem objects and both must be thread safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Where` operation or any other collection operation is thread safe, for example if it wasn't thread safe there could be an error in the `Where` operation if anyone changed the items count in other thread in the same time, but changing the `Status` property is not related to the collection and it is not thread safe.